# Insert new user to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following snippet which is currently located inside the create account button.

```
  self.ref.child("Users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["fb_id": fb_id, "first_name": f_name, "last_name": l_name, "email": email])
```

I currently receive the error `type user! has no member uid` which I understand because I haven't created a user for this new person yet, I have gone through all documentation on [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data) however I can't find the solution I'm looking for.

Can someone please share their knowledge on how I go about inserting a new user.

Comment: whats the problem with this. .. looks ok to me

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 apologies, managed to get this resolved I had to change user! to my variable name auth which inside contained the uid of the user,

Comment: ok .. no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the uid with `.child("\(FIRAuth.auth().currentUser.uid)")`, if you haven't stored a value in user variable `child(user!.uid)` has no sense.